# Shifting eigenvalues via skew-symmetric product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $X$ be an $n\times n$ real *positive definite* matrix and consider the following matrix
$$
Y=SX,
$$
where $S$ is an $n\times n$ real *skew-symmetric* matrix. Let $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^n$, $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_2\ge\cdots\ge \lambda_n$, be the ordered eigenvalues of $X$ and let $\{\mu_i\}_{i=1}^n$, $\Re[\mu_1]\ge \Re[\mu_2]\ge\cdots\ge \Re[\mu_n]$ be the ordered (w.r.t. real parts) eigenvalues of $Y$.

> **My question.** Does there exist a skew-symmetric $S$ such that the real part of the eigenvalues of $Y$ are greater than those of $X$, that is,
>   $$
> \Re[\mu_i] \ge \lambda_i, \quad i=1,\dots,n \ \ ?
> $$
>   If not, does there exist a skew-symmetric $S$ such that the largest real part of the eigenvalues of $Y$ is greater than the largest eigenvalue of $X$, that is,
>   $$
> \Re[\mu_1] \ge \lambda_1 \ \ ?
> $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Y=SX$ is similar to the skew-symmetric matrix $X^{1/2}SX^{1/2}$. Therefore the real parts of the eigenvalues of $Y$ are always zero and they cannot possibly be greater than any eigenvalue of $X$ (which is positive).